# How to manage Sitecore security for anonymous users from a web site

Tags: .net, security, sitecore, sitecore6

I have interesting task with security for sitecore web site and I need to get some ideas or best practice how to do work with it.

I have some sitecore web site without any custom sitecore security (SS) (SS using just for sitecore admin page). Users can login to the site with some extra service, this service return user roles and permission as well.

I would like to map external roles to my sitecore roles (and manage access to some site pages with Sitecore security).

I have an idea to add some sitecore roles or domain to sitecore anonymous user after user login via external service, but I am not sure that this is good solution to manage access.
What can I do in my case?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own custom membership provider and map roles / users between the external service and Sitecore.

Here is some documentation from Sitecore SDN about custom  membership providers for Sitecore:

http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/sc61keywords/membership_providers_a4.pdf

http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/modules/ad/low-level_sitecore_cms_security_and_custom_providers-usletter.pdf

http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/sc61keywords/security_api_cookbook_usletter.pdf